# Rails Postgres query Position of item relative to others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a model against [Amazon's SQS Standard Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html#standard-queues-message-order) which can send updates out of order.

My goal is to properly order them.

I am longpolling to copy all data from the queue into my DB.

table example - lets say I fetch some messages and process them

```
id | published_at | run_at | payload
1  | 1:11pm       | nil    | ...
2  | 1:12pm       | nil    | ...
3  | 1:13pm       | nil    | ...
4  | 1:14pm       | nil    | ...
5  | 1:15pm       | nil    | ...
```

Then I fetch some more, and we can see that a few odd messages are now outdated.

```
id | published_at | run_at | payload
1  | 1:11pm       | 1:15   | ...
2  | 1:12pm       | 1:15   | ...
3  | 1:13pm       | 1:15   | ...
4  | 1:14pm       | 1:15   | ...
5  | 1:15pm       | 1:15   | ...
6  | 1:13pm       | nil    | ...
7  | 1:14pm       | nil   | ...
8  | 1:16pm       | nil   | ...
```

if i were to order by published_at, you can see that the queue needs to be re-processed starting at `ID=6` down to make sure messages are processed in order.

```
id | published_at | run_at | payload
1  | 1:11pm       | 1:15   | ...
2  | 1:12pm       | 1:15   | ...
3  | 1:13pm       | 1:15   | ...
6  | 1:13pm       | nil    | ...
4  | 1:14pm       | 1:15   | ...
7  | 1:14pm       | nil   | ...
5  | 1:15pm       | 1:15   | ...
8  | 1:16pm       | nil   | ...
```

There is value in processing data accurately, and very little problem with processing twice so re-running is not a problem.

I am mostly curious how best to best find the oldest item that has not been ran, and start running from that moment forward.

Currently doing:

```
#  fetch oldest publish_time that has not been ran
first_publish_time = AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).minimum(:publish_time)

if first_publish_time
  #  start there, and process in ascending order
  AnyOfferChange.order("publish_time DESC").where("publish_time >= ?",first_publish_time).reverse.each(&:process!)
end
```

It feels quite fragile, I'd like to fetch the position and use it as a limit.

```
limit = AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).order("publish_time ASC").pluck("POSITION SOMETHIN(SOMETHING)").first

if limit > 0
  #  start there, and process in ascending order
  AnyOfferChange.order("publish_time DESC").limit(limit).reverse.each(&:process!)
end
```

Comment: Why don't you run only `AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).where('publish_time >= ?', first_publish_time).order(:publish_time).each(&:process!)`? (avoiding re-running). Also, if you first fetch the smallest `publish_time` having `null` for `run_at`, then you don't have to ask for higher that this `publish_time` as it is already the smallest one. `AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).find_each(&:process!)` would be simpler

Comment: because then the updates will be processed `unordered` which means the final resting data is incorrect

Comment: @MrYoshiji for example look at table 3, if i process where run_at:nil THEN i would process ids=(6,7,8). But if 6 and 4 happen to affect similar objects then it would have incorrect data, because the most recently ran update would be 6 even though 4 had a later publish date.

Comment: @BlairAnderson Not if you order the result using `AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).order(:publish_time).each(&:process!)`, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The follow SQL query will give you the oldest *publish_time*:

```
AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).minimum(:publish_time)
```

Or, if you want one record:

```
AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).order(publish_time: :asc).first
```

This will limit the SQL query the oldest row that has not ran.

Fetch all records that not ran from old till new:

```
result = AnyOfferChanges.where(run_at: nil).order(publish_time: :asc)
# or
result = AnyOfferChanges.where(run_at: nil).order(:publish_time) # Defaults to :asc

result.each(&:process!) # Process result. See note below for batch info.
```

Fetch all records that did not ran with exactly the oldest publish_time (that did not ran):

```
# See note below to prevent unwanted SQL execution for the statements 
# below when executing in the terminal.

# Create shorthand.
any_offer_changes = AnyOfferChange.arel_table

# Build query parts.
not_ran = AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil)
oldest_publish_time = not_ran.select(any_offer_changes[:publish_time].minimum)

# All records that not ran with with the oldest publish time.
result = not_ran.where(publish_time: oldest_publish_time)
result.each(&:process!) # Process result. See note below for batch info.
```

This will result in fetching all records with the lowest publish time in one SQL query, using a sub-query.

The reason I use another way than `AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).minimum(:publish_time)` to fetch the minimum for the last part. Is that this query will break the chain and create multiple SQL queries instead of one. Whereas `AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).select(any_offer_changes[:run_at].minimum)` will keep the chain intact when used in a *where* statement.

**notes:**

*unwanted SQL execution*

When run one by one this will result in multiple queries since the *#inspect* (used to show you the result) will trigger the SQL to execute. In the terminal follow each statement with `;nil`, to prevent execution when building a *#where* chain. This is not needed when executed in a script.

*using "batches"*

For large amounts of records you may have to limit the resulting values. Rails support batches, but they don't respect the given order. To keep the order you can create your own batch, although probably less efficient. This can be done like so:

```
result = AnyOfferChange.where(run_at: nil).order(:publish_time).limit(100)
result.each(&:process!) while result.reload.any?
```

Assuming you set the *run_at* attribute in *#process!*, otherwise the above will result in an endless loop.

Comment: I think you're missing the very first sentence of my question, that i get changes `out of order` and I need to make sure they are processed in order....

Comment: @BlairAnderson They are processed in order, that's why I pass `.order(:publish_time)`.

Comment: You can pass `.where(any_offer_changes[:publish_time].lt(2.minutes.ago))` as extra restriction to the chain if you wan't to make sure you don't process the newest incoming records.